# Finding the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $f_n(x)=\cos(x)\cos(2x)\cdots\cos(nx)$ satisfies $|f_n''(0)|>2023$. (Putnam 2023 A1)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, inequality, trigonometry

Putnam 2023, Problem A1:

> For a positive integer $n$, let $f_n(x)=\cos (x) \cos (2 x) \cos (3 x) \cdots \cos (n x)$. Find the smallest $n$ such that $|f_n''(0)|>2023$ .
>
> Note: Here, $f_n''(x)$ denotes the double derivative of $f_n(x)$.

**My Attempt :** Observe that we can write $$f_n(x)=\cos (x) \cos (2 x) \cos (3 x) \cdots \cos (n x)=\frac{1}{2^n}. \prod \limits_{k=1}^n ({e^{ikx} + e^{-ikx}})$$ But how can I get from here that $$|f_n''(0)| = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} > 2023 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad n \geq 18$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See AoPS discussion ... https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h3209179p29337598

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly the easiest solution to this problem.

Denote by $y(x)=f_n(x)$.

Now from definition

$$y(x) =\prod_{r=1}^n \cos(rx)$$
And hence that $y(0)=1$ since $\cos(0) =1$.

Then taking the natural logarithm on both sides since for our evaluation the cosine will be $>0$, we see that
$$\ln(y(x)) = \ln\left(\prod_{r=1}^n \cos(rx)\right) = \sum_{r=1}^n\ln(\cos(rx))$$
Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ to get that
$$\frac{y’(x)}{y(x)}= \sum_{r=1}^n -r\tan(rx) \implies y’(x) = -y(x)\cdot \sum_{r=1}^n r\tan(rx)$$

Therefore, $y’(0)=0$.

Again differentiate w.r.t. $x$ so that
$$y’’(x) = -y’(x)\cdot \sum_ {r=0}^{n} r\tan(rx) -y(x)\cdot \sum_{r=1}^n r^2 \sec^2(rx)$$
Putting $x=0$ again, we see that
$$y’’(0) = -\sum_{r=1}^n r^2 \sec^2(0) = -\sum_{r=1}^n r^2 = -\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Therefore it follows that $|y’’(0)| = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ since $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

Now $|y’’(0)|>2023$. Then it is easy to work out that at $n=17$, $y’’(0)= -1785$ and at $n=18$, $y’’(0) =-2109$, so that all $n \geq 18$ are solutions.

Answer (score 2):

It would be simplest to consider Taylor series instead. Consider

$$\prod_{k=1}^n\cos(kx) = \prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac{k^2x^2}{2}+O(x^4)\right)$$

$$= 1 - \frac{\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\right)}{2}x^2 + O(x^4)$$

where by Taylor's theorem $f''(0)$ is exactly equal to the summation in parentheses. Therefore

$$|f''(0)|=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}>2023\implies n\geq 18$$

Answer (score 2):

Forget about signs.

When you evaluate the second derivative at zero, any term with a $\sin$ is going to be zero, so only terms with cosines will contribute to your evaluation of $f_n''(0)$.

On the first derivative, you have a bunch of terms with one sine and $n-1$ cosines. For each term, when you take another derivative, you will have either two sines and $n-2$ cosines or $n$ cosines. Since you are only interested in the terms without sines, only the terms with cosines survive. These terms appear from the derivation of one cosine (say  $\cos(rx)$) on the first derivative when applying the product rule (so you have $-r\sin(rx)$) and then applying the derivation of that very same term on the second derivative (so you have $-r^2\cos(rx)$) when applying the product rule again to each summand. Hence,
$$ |f_n''(0)|= \sum_{r=1}^n r^2 \prod_{i=1}^n \cos(i\cdot 0).$$

I leave you the rest :)

Comment: hint: there is something called Square pyramidal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Take logarithm,

differentiate $1st$ then $2nd$ time

Put $x=0$

$f_n(0)=1$ and $f'_n(0)=0$

Put it to $f''_n(x)$ equation, take modulus both side

Arrive at summation of squares.

From their you can deal using numerical approximation as $2n^3 ≈ 12000$

Lead to strictly between $15$ and $20$

Finally arrive at $18$